# Different types of Blackboard Bold in the same document

Tags: fonts, package-options, blackboard, mtpro

I am using `mtpro2` package and it has 7 (!) different options for the Blackboard Bold (BB) to choose from. However only 2 of them provide BB version of Greek letters. And in both cases the result is italic which hurts the eyes when it comes to `\mathbb{N, Z, Q, R}` and `\mathbb{C}`.

I was wondering is there a way to have two sets on the same document, maybe with a new command for the Greek letters?

Comment: Try `\let\mathbblatin\mathbb` _after_ `\usepackage{amssymb}`, but _before_ `\usepackage{mtpro2}`, and then `\mathbblatin{N}` in your document. This should give you the AMS blackboard bold `N`. Does it work?

Comment: It had no effect. Blackboard bold N appears as before ...

Comment: Have you looked into the `mathalfa` package and its capabilities of having various math alphabets side by side?

Comment: Yes, but it lets you set only one mathbb font and none of the options have Blackboard bold for Greek alphabet.

Comment: I don't have access to `mtpro2` to test it, but @Hendrik Vogt's suggestion works for me substituting `mathpazo` for `mtpro2`.  What does `\show\mathbb` give after loading `mtpro2`?  Or `\expandafter\show\csname mathbb \endcsname` if it's protected.

Answer (score 4):

Try `\let\mathbblatin\mathbb` after `\usepackage{amssymb}`, but before `\usepackage{mtpro2}`.

Then `\mathbblatin{N}` in your document. This should give you the AMS blackboard bold `N`.

Comment: amssymb and mtpro2 can not be loaded together, so I actually would like to delete your answer. OK?

Answer (score 1):

`amssymb` and `mtpro2` can not be loaded together.

To use two different blackboard bold alphabets in your document, proceed as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mtpbb]{mtpro2}  %% to have Times-compatible Blackboard Bold as \mathbb

% \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbgr}{U}{mt2bb}{m}{it}  %% to have Times-compatible Blackboard Bold Italic as \mathbbgr
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbgr}{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{it}  %% to have Times-compatible Holey Roman Bold Italic as \mathbbgr

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \mathbb{NZQRC} \mbox{ versus } \mathbbgr{NZQRC \alpha\Gamma}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image: two blackboard bold alphabets from mtpro2]